# "sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename" - error upon insmod

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Below is the problem execution sequence, am writing a new platform driver that also creates sysfs entries

- insmod works
- no sysfs read/writes from userland
- rmmod works
- insmod works
- sudo bash -c "echo xxx > /sys/devices/platform/xphy/chipname"
- rmmod works - but does not remove symbolic link /sys/bus/platform/devices/xphy -> ../../../devices/platform/xphy
- insmod fails - because-  sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/bus/platform/devices/xphy'

below did not work when called during module/driver exit..

```
//sysfs_remove_link(&device->dev.kobj, "xphy");
//sysfs_remove_link(&device->dev.kobj, "bus/platform/devices/xphy");
ks = bus_get_kset(device->dev.bus);
ko = kset_find_obj(ks, "xphy");
sysfs_remove_link(ko, "xphy");
ko = kset_find_obj(bus_get_kset(device->dev.bus), "xphy");
if (ko) {
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "dereferencing xphy sysfs kernel object!\n");
    kobject_put(ko);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "deleting xphy sysfs kernel object!\n");
    kobject_del(ko);
}
```